# npm ERR! semver.simplifyRange is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, express-generator

Trying to follow the [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) getting started tutorial.

I generated an app and ran `npm install` following the provided instructions.

```
> npx express-generator --view=pug myapp
> npm install
npm ERR! semver.simplifyRange is not a function
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2021-03-21T04_58_39_577Z-debug.log
```

The relevant portion from the log

```
555 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/longest/-/longest-1.0.1.tgz 706ms
556 timing reifyNode:node_modules/longest Completed in 751ms
557 timing metavuln:cache:get:security-advisory:transformers:qlM2fO34VL+rWNeim/6QsbBJFfHtRf4Z7FAoL1JLqVXlvg5FMRxw1WstcKR09WDDJCiJsPPrdRJugEOTZ6eGZA== Completed in 22ms
558 verbose stack TypeError: semver.simplifyRange is not a function
558 verbose stack     at Advisory.[calculateRange] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/metavuln-calculator/lib/advisory.js:191:16)
558 verbose stack     at Advisory.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/metavuln-calculator/lib/advisory.js:148:28)
558 verbose stack     at Calculator.[calculate] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/metavuln-calculator/lib/index.js:59:14)
558 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 0)
558 verbose stack     at async Map.[init] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/audit-report.js:177:7)
558 verbose stack     at async Map.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/audit-report.js:105:7)
```

New to node and I have no idea what this means. Looks to be a problem with npm and not Express?

I tried running `npm cache clean --force` and deleting `node_modules` but neither helped.

If it is relevant, npm version 7.6.3 and node version 15.11.0.

Comment: I get the same error trying to:  
- init a react-native project with npx.  ```npx init react-native myProject```  
- installing react-native globally with ```npm install -g react-native```  
I have the same version of npm and node

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution was to install older version of semver and update npm itself to version 7.7.0.
I used the commands:

```
sudo npm install -g semver@7.2.0
```

and then

```
sudo npm install -g npm@7.7.0
```

After it worked

Comment: for me just worked `sudo npm install -g semver@7.2.0`

`❯ node -v v15.11.0`

`❯ npm -v  7.6.3`

Answer (score 0):

After another another round of updates from the package manager, I ran into more problems (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66997215/9614249)).

From the question linked above I found installing node directly from the [nodejs website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) to be a more permanent and robust solution.