# npm install fails with 'subset is not a function'

Tags: node.js, npm

I have `node v15.14.0` and `npm 7.8.0` on `Arch Linux x86_64` (installed from that distro's repos).

Starting a project in an empty directory with `npm init` and then trying to install something with `npm i <blah>` always fails in the same fashion. An example, run in `$HOME/tmp`:

```
$ npm i btoa
npm ERR! subset is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     $HOME/.npm/_logs/2021-04-08T00_32_19_504Z-debug.log
```

That log file reads as follows:

```
0 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'i', 'btoa' ]
1 info using npm@7.8.0
2 info using node@v15.14.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 0ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 0ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:$HOME/tmp/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:$HOME/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:/usr/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 5ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 5ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
20 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 1ms
21 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 1ms
22 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 1ms
23 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 0ms
24 timing npm:load Completed in 9ms
25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
26 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
28 timing idealTree:init Completed in 13ms
29 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 3ms
30 silly idealTree buildDeps
31 silly fetch manifest btoa@*
32 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/btoa 193ms (from cache)
33 silly placeDep ROOT btoa@1.2.1 KEEP for: tmp@1.0.0 want: *
34 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 198ms
35 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 199ms
36 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 0ms
37 timing idealTree Completed in 217ms
38 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 217ms
39 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 0ms
40 silly reify moves {}
41 timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
42 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 0ms
43 timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
44 timing reify:unpack Completed in 0ms
45 timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
46 timing build:queue Completed in 0ms
47 timing build:deps Completed in 1ms
48 timing build Completed in 1ms
49 timing reify:build Completed in 1ms
50 timing reify:trash Completed in 0ms
51 timing command:install Completed in 230ms
52 verbose stack TypeError: subset is not a function
52 verbose stack     at Arborist.[saveIdealTree] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:956:37)
52 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:138:39
52 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:134:5)
52 verbose stack     at async Install.install (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:137:5)
53 verbose cwd $HOME/tmp
54 verbose Linux 5.10.25-1-lts
55 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "btoa"
56 verbose node v15.14.0
57 verbose npm  v7.8.0
58 error subset is not a function
59 verbose exit 1
```

So you can see that

- my "global" modules live in `/usr/lib/node_modules` (where I can install just fine with `sudo npm install -g`);
- the `subset` function seems to pop up when the `install` command calls

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js
```

I've checked that that file defines

```
const {subset} = require('semver')
```

How do I fix this?

**Edit:**

This is to address a comment below: this `subset` issue occurs *regardless* of what I try to install. `btoa` was nothing but an example.

Comment: Why would you need `btoa` to begin with? Node can already natively convert any data to base64 using Buffer's `toString('base64')`, and convert from base64 using `Buffer.from(data, 'base64')`?

Comment: It was only an example. The issue replicates with *any* `npm` package whatsoever.

Comment: Do `npm ls` and `npm ls -g` return without an error?

Comment: also note that `npm install -g` should never need `sudo` (because that would be an _insane_ security risk. NPM installations can and have been known to, run arbitrary code that can do everything from installing backdoors to running `rm -rf /`). If `npm i -g` doesn't work without it, something went very wrong, and it's probably time to reinstall node...

Comment: `npm ls -g` always works fine; `npm ls` errors with `extraneous modules` unless I remove `$HOME/node_modules`; if I do, it's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to replicate your problem by changing `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/ranges/subset.js` to be an empty file. Sounds like something went wrong during your installation of `npm` and at least one dependency (`semver`) didn't fully install. Or maybe somehow something happened later that overwrote the file to be an empty file.

Your best bet is to reinstall `node` and `npm`. But there are narrower things you can try. You say `npm install -g` is working. I find that surprising, but because that's the case, you can try `npm install -g npm` to reinstall `npm` itself. That should fix things. If that doesn't work, you can try `npm install --force -g npm`.

But again: Your best bet is to reinstall `node` and `npm`.

Comment: This fails on multiple levels: `npm install -g` (with or without `--force`) *always* gives me permission errors for renaming files under `/usr/lib/node_modules`, hence my need for sudo; reinstalling `npm` through the distro's package manager did nothing; and `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/ranges/subset.js` looks fine..

Comment: I eventually gave up on my package manager's `node` and `npm`: too much of a headache. I went and installed the [canonical](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) version, and all is well (I can `npm install`, and also `npm install -g` without `sudo`). I will just accept this answer; thank you!

Comment: what helped me was `sudo npm install -g npm`. I tried to uninstall/re-install npm via pacman but that did not help.

Answer (score 4):

For those who miss [papanito's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229864/papanito) comment

```
sudo npm i -g npm
```

Worked for me on Arch.